# Trying to link to users.show page from posts.show page and cant find user id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an association between users and posts, where a post belongs to user and a user has many posts.
When viewing the post show view the post is rendered with the url

> http://localhost:3000/posts/21

and when I click the `= link_to @post.user.name`, `user_path` on the `posts` page I get the `url`

```
http://localhost:3000/users/21
```

and the `error`

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /users/21
Couldn't find User with 'id'=21
```

In this case the user id I should be redirected to should be `/users/1`
I cant figure out why the image id and the user id are not changing since the the image with "id"=21 belongs to user "id"=1

My posts view `show.html.haml`

```
= image_tag @post.image.url (:medium)
%h1= @post.title
%p= @post.link
%p= @post.description
= link_to @post.user.name, user_path
%h2
= @post.get_upvotes.size
likes
= link_to "Like", like_post_path(@post), method: :get

%h2.comment_count= pluralize(@post.comments.count, "Comment")
- @comments.each do |comment|
    .comment
        %p.username= comment.user.name
        %p.content= comment.content

= render 'comments/form'


= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(@post)
= link_to "Destroy", post_path(@post), method: :delete, data: {confirm:     "Are you sure?"}
= link_to "Home", root_path
```

and my users controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def index
    @users = User.all
end

def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @posts = @user.posts.order("created_at DESC")
end

end
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `user_path(@user)`?

Comment: it should be `link_to @post.user.name, user_path(@post.user)`

Comment: Oh yeah, `@post.user`. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the `(@post.user)` on the end of

`= link_to @post.user.name, user_path`

so

`link_to @post.user.name, user_path(@post.user)`

fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

Use simply

```
= link_to @post.user.name, @post.user
```